# Vagrant has detected that the VirtualBox installed is not supported

Tags: windows, vagrant, virtualbox

Slight issue with Vagrant; I have the latest download of Vagrant (for Windows) installed. I've been able to download the files just fine.

However, after downloading the box, I've got a slight issue, in which when typing Vagrant up, it says:

"Vagrant has detected that the VirtualBox installed is not supported [...] 4.0, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3"

But I have 4.3.

[image: screenshot]

Yes, the PATH var does link to VBoxManage.exe

Any help?

Comment: Alright, this is just nuts. I installed VirtualBox 4.2.14, and Vagrant detected it... BUT it's not supported as it has some 'major' bug.

So, cool, I decide to upgrade to 4.2.16, as it suggested me to do so. NOPE. Apparently I'm on an unsupported edition again.

Come on, WHY

Comment: Nope, nothing registry wise indicates the version is anything, other than 4.3.0

Comment: I have the same with vagrant 1.6.5 + Vbox 4.3.16 on windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Might be [this issue](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/2562), i.e. VirtualBox bug, but Vagrant 1.5 (unreleased at the moment) will try to get the version multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

So basically vagrant is not supporting older or newer versions/releases of virtualbox.

Vagrant supports only these versions: 4.0, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3

So to solve this problem, I would suggest that you download if you don't have the older version of virtualbox source and then run the installation for the older version and that would solve the problem.

I have had upgraded virtualbox to 5.0.0 and that broke my vagrant boxes. I tried everything, but no chance.

So I went and reinstalled virtualbox version 4.30 and that downgraded well and vagrant is up and running.

I hope this might help.

Thanks!